# Cleanly perform map() over Set collection state but still rerender on state changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-structures

I have a Set collection of values. I want to iterate over these and render a component for each value.

I understand I can't use `forEach()` as I need to return something which is why `map()` is highly recommended.
But again I have a `Set` and **not** an `Array`.

I could use `Array.from(set)` **but it no longer rerenders** when the Set state changes, even though I could very well see that the state has indeed changed.

What would be the cleanest way to map() over the values of a Set collection in a state?

```
...

const [selected, setSelected] = useState(new Set([]))

const addToSelected = data => {
    setSelected(state => state.add(data))
    console.log(selected)
  }

render(
    {selected &&
      Array.from(selected).map(data => {
        return (
          <QuestionsItem
          key={data.message}
          data={data}
          negative
          callback={removeSelected}
          />
       )
    })}
)
```

Comment: `Array.from(set)` doesn't mutate the set. I don't see why it should have any effect on the set, including any rerender logic that listens for changes to the set. Using `Array.from` should be fine—I'm guessing there's something else going on.

Comment: @Christian could you provide some code? Are you using a class of functional components?

Comment: @weltschmerz to my understanding, Array.from() is taking the value of set on the first render, meaning it doesn't really "listen" for changes to set and thus doesn't get updated when set changes.

Comment: @Rostyslav Updated

Comment: Sets in JavaScript are mutable so when you're doing `state.add(data)` it's returning the same Set, and React thinks that nothing changed in your `selected` because it's still the same Set.

Comment: @Christian make sure you are using Sets correctly in meaning that you might actually need set values instead Set itself ` Array.from(selected.values)`

Comment: Something like the [`useSet` hook](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/useSet.ts) might work for your use case. It creates a new Set on every mutation, which is likely efficient enough unless this component changes a lot.

Comment: @Rostyslav That's not the issue. `Array.from(set)` returns the same thing as `Array.from(set.values())`. (And `values` is a function.)

Comment: @Christian Is your set part of the component's state? Your component won't rerender otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- JavaScript Sets are mutable, which means your `.add` calls don't change anything that React's basic `useState` is able to notice; your `selected` variable stays the same even as you add things to it

A simple approach is to always use an Array and do the duplicate value checking yourself. This will work with minimal fuss:

```js
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([])

const addToSelected = data => {
  if (selected.indexOf(data) === -1) {
    setSelected(state => [...state, data])
  }
  console.log(selected)
}

render(
    selected.map(data => {
      return (
        <QuestionsItem
        key={data.message}
        data={data}
        negative
        callback={removeSelected}
        />
      )
  })
)
```